# Access SQL Date Format Inconsistent

Tags: mysql, vba, date, ms-access

I currently have a table in my database keeping track of a start date and end date for a service. I need to compare a date entered by the user to see if it is between the start and end dates. My issue right now is that in the table, access stores that start date as `DD/MM/YYYY`, the textbox in my form that the user puts their date in is formated as `DD/MM/YYYY`. However, once I hit VBA and run an SQL query, it reads the date as `MM/DD/YYYY`.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE #09/01/2018# BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

My test entry is:

table:

```
startDate     endDate      service
08/01/2018    02/02/2018   ABC
```

This should return this entry, however as it reads it as `MM/DD/YYYY` it does not. If I enter `#13/01/2018#` it returns the entry as it detects that `13` is the date and cannot be a month. How could I correct this so that it takes `09/01/2018` and returns the entry as well?

Comment: You could use [VBA's format function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which is available to the Access query engine, to return all dates in a unified format.  Example: `Format(<Date Field / Date Var>, "yyyymmdd")`.

Comment: That is very interesting as datetimes follow your computer's region settings. Regions with date first should render accordingly in all Access objects: tables, queries, and modules. Possibly, your *date* field is a text field and not datetime.

Comment: If you use the format() command you are changing the date to a string, this will then not work in many situations. See the link in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an VBA query then your observations are correct. In the Query designer these will work as expected.

Review Allen Browne's excellent explanation here; http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html 
with solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should use either the "reverse" US sequence or the ISO sequence:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE #2018/01/09# BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

or, if you build it from code:

```
SearchDate = SomeDateValue
SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE #" & Format(SearchDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# BETWEEN startDate AND endDate"
```

or, if you always search for today:

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Date() BETWEEN startDate AND endDate"
```